# SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user Mdtappsrv\mdtusr

Tags: sql, connection

I have created a local useraccount on the server (Mdtappsrv\mdtusr), from this account able to login to sql server and can access the database MDT. but when i try fetch the same database from IIS, getting 
SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user Mdtappsrv\mdtusr

webconfig

Answer (score 0):

Since SQL was installed along with the MDT installation, there was no option to enable mixed mode or to set SA password. To fix this problem created a new SQL instance, this can  be achieved by installation of SQL express edition again.
During the installation will get option for changing to Mixed mode and setting up the SA password.